# Preventing a plugin from executing a lifecycle phase

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I invoke maven using the following command sequence

```
C:>\mvn install tomcat7:redeploy
```

This produces the following (heavily) edited output

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ geomaster ---
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ geomaster >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ geomaster ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ geomaster ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ geomaster <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ geomaster ---
```

Please ignore the fact that I have no resources or source code in the project. This is not the crux of the question.

The `install` target is used to place the generated war into the maven repository. The `tomcat7:redeploy` target is used to place the generated war into a tomcat server.

I have tried various invocations and different configurations but I cannot prevent the tomcat plugin from performing it's own build despite the `install` target having just done it.

The surefire plugin seems to have some 'smarts' as it has detected that it has been run before. Why can't maven have this 'smarts' also?

There is additional infomation about the tomcat plugin can be found here: [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)

While the second build as executed by the tomcat plugin would not do anything substantial, even in a more substantial project, how can I prevent it from being executed at all as it is entirely redundant?

Is this a bug in either maven or the tomcat plugin? Could this be the basis for a request for an enhancement? Or this expected behaviour that has to lived with?

Comment: I can't find a `redeploy` goal in the tomcat plugin. Do you mean `deploy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Tomcat page you link to regarding the [`deploy` goal](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html), it states that it:

> *Invokes the execution of the [lifecycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html) package prior to executing itself.*

So that is why it is doing its own build. This is a deliberate feature, and as far as I can tell can not be turned off.

However the [`deploy-only`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-only-mojo.html) goal exists which:

> *Deploy a WAR to Tomcat without forking the package lifecycle*

So if you change your command to be:

```
mvn install tomcat7:deploy-only
```

then it should do what you want.

Comment: Too much documentation - bleary eyes. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: How to integrate tomcat7:deploy-only (without forking the package lifecycle)  in maven using profile, so that I can only deploy WAR on multiple server and what will be the command for it